# How to update GitLab CI/CD variables after repository name change?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have recently changed my repository name in GitLab. Is there any way I can make sure that the stock GitLab CI/CD variables are updated to reflect the new repository name without manually overriding them in my CI/CD pipelines?

Hypothetically, lets say the repository's original name is 'A' and its new name is 'B'. Once I've changed the repository's name, the GitLab CI/CD variables that are set automatically by GitLab remain unchanged. For example the stock CI/CD variable `CI_PROJECT_NAME` is still `A` when I want it to now be `B` to reflect the new repository name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#CI_RROJECT_NAME), the variable `CI_PROJECT_NAME` is derived from the directory of the project. This can be changed under `Settings` -> `General` -> `Avanced` -> `Change path`. After editing the project path here, `CI_PROJECT_NAME` changes its value accordingly.

In your case I would blindly guess that you just changed the project name
under `Settings` -> `General` -> `Project name`, which is only used for displaying in the UI.